# Controller accept class as JSON Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, class

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Add([FromBody]Person Object)
    {
        if (!Object.IsValid()) return false;
        Repository.Add(Object);
        return true;
    }

public class Person : Model
{
    public Age Age;
    public string Name;

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        if (Age == null) return false;

        return true;
    }
}

public class Age
{
    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }

    public Age() {}
    public Age(DateTime Creation)
    {
        this.Creation = Creation;
    }

    public int Compute()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Year - Creation.Year; // Leap Year?
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of the current code. 
The json i'm posting:

```
{
    "Age": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00",
    "Name": "Humberg"
}
```

How is it possible to accept a custom class via. json? If i replace public Age Age; with public DateTime Age; then this code works, and the date get's parsed correctly. If i don't a runtime exception occurs because "Object" was null (probably due to an internal deserialization error).

Comment: You should also consider initializing the `Age` property in the definition of the `Person` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json you post needs to match the model structure you want it to bind to (if you just want built-in model binding to just do it's thing).

i.e.
try posting:

```
{
    "Name" : "Humberg",
    "Age" : {
        "Creation" : "2016-01-01T00:00:00.0000000-00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh, I already tried that, but i didn't use the correct date format then. Thank you! Unfortunately there is a timer on accepting your answer, but this is it.